# strcpy_s does not return properly, and further code is not executed

Tags: c++

Can someone explain why this only prints out `Hello World1`, and then hangs for 1 second before coming back to the command prompt, without printing anything else?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char    tchar[4];
    cout << "Hello World1\n";
    strcpy_s(tchar, sizeof(tchar), "Dick");
    cout << "Hello World2\n";
    cout << tchar << "\n";
    cout << "Hello World3\n";
}
```

Comment: `tchar` is too small. Don’t forget the null termination. `strcpy_s` is aborting

Comment: These 'safe' routines from Microsoft are a menace.  It would be much nicer if they just truncated the string.

Comment: @PaulSanders no. truncating would just be hiding a bug. Your software is expecting to have copied "something" but it would just display (and handle) a different string "somet"

Comment: @PaulSanders [strcpy_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) is C11.

Comment: As per documentation, the reason for the abort behavior is because `strcpy_s` detects an error and calls the (default) constraint handler, which ultimately aborts your program. IDK why you get the one second delay. If you want a better response then [set your own constraint handler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/set_constraint_handler_s).

Comment: OK, these 'safe' routines are a menace.  Sorry, but I don't like them.  Aborting a program like that with no diagnostic is seldom helpful.

Comment: Why tag `C++` if you are using `C` specific function? I recommend drop use of `strcpy_s` and just use `std::string`.

Comment: strcpy_s is not a part of the C++ language.

Comment: @PaulSanders perhaps it's more accurate to say that C-style string manipulation is a menace :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes, I'm with you there (isn't it funny how people often miss the point)

Comment: @GianPaolo From cppreference (their example): `dst = "", r = 22 abort_handler_s was called in response to a runtime-constraint violation. The runtime-constraint violation was caused by the following expression in strcpy_s: (s1max <= (s2_len=strnlen_s(s2, s1max)) ) (in string_s.c:62)" Aborted`. Good luck debugging that! (If it happens in the field)

Comment: @PaulSanders that's a point, I agree. I'm on the side "better than program crashes than the program behave randomly", but yes, _good luck debugging that_. std:string can make everything easier, as always, c++ beats c in this kind of things

Comment: @GianPaolo Oh yes, you don't want to overrun a buffer.

Comment: @PaulSanders with strcopy_s you don't have a buffer overrun, your program simply stops (crashes): with _behave randomly_ I mean that if strcopy_s would just truncate the string as you are suggesting,  your program would end in an inconsistent state more or less: your code assume that in dest char* there is the string "something", instead there's a string "some"

Comment: @GianPaolo I don't call truncating a string random behaviour. If that's what `strcpy_s` was documented as doing then one could decide if that is acceptable in any given situation. If a programmer is worried that they might overflow a buffer (which, ofc, one must never do) then check (using `assert`, say) *at the point of failure*, not inside some library function. Then at least you get useful file and line number information when your program dies. (I go further - there are tools I can use on the platforms I support to get a stack trace emailed back to base, but that's changing the subject.)